# compare the triplet hackerrank why is forEach not working as a solution

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I know there's multiple discussions already around this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem?isFullScreen=true). however, I'm curious as to why exactly does this solution `X` using `forEach` where you're comparing the value from array `A` against the same-positioned index-targeted value from array `B` as compared to solution `Y` where you're targeting both array elements by the `index` of `forEach`

Solution X

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    
    let pointsA = 0; 
    let pointsB = 0;
    a.forEach((value, index) => {
        if(value > b[index]) {
           pointsA=+1
        } else if (value < b[index]) {
            pointsB=+1
        } 
        else {
            return;
        }
    })
    return [pointsA, pointsB];
}
```

Solution Y

```
function compareTriplets(a, b) {
    
    let ascore = 0, bscore = 0;
    a.forEach((item, i) => {
        (a[i] > b[i]) && ascore++;
        (b[i] < b[i]) && bscore++;
    });

    return [ascore, bscore];
}
```

inputs:

```
17 28 30
99 16 8
```

Comment: Solution `X` do exactly the same as `Y`. They are both using `value` for element of first array and `index` for the second one

Comment: sorry bout that, I went ahead and edited it with the right correspondences this time.

Comment: So now the answer is "because it's how the author wanted" no performance difference between the two.

Comment: yeah but solution X does not work. it returns `[1,1]` while it should return `[2,1]`

Comment: That's because you have `pointsA=+1` instead of `pointsA+=1`

Comment: oh totally missed that one out. thanks!

Comment: "*I know there's multiple discussions already around this question*" - which question? Are you referring to the hackerrank problem? Please quote the problem statement and cite the source. Also please link those multiple other discussions.